# Converting Class to function with hooks

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, tsx

I'm stuck with converting a Class component to a function / const while using hooks.

I'm getting this Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

I googled this warning but only saw this warning with Classes, did I convert this Class wrong?

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const position = new Animated.ValueXY()
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(props.index || 0)

  const rotate = position.x.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2],
    outputRange: ['-30deg', '0deg', '10deg'],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  })

  const rotateAndTranslate = {
    transform: [
      {
        rotate: rotate,
      },
      position.getTranslateTransform(),
    ],
  }

  const likeOpacity = position.x.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2],
    outputRange: [0, 0, 1],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  })
  const dislikeOpacity = position.x.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2],
    outputRange: [1, 0, 0],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  })

  const nextCardOpacity = position.x.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2],
    outputRange: [1, 0, 1],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  })
  const nextCardScale = position.x.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2],
    outputRange: [1, 0.8, 1],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        position.setValue({ x: gestureState.dx, y: gestureState.dy })
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
        if (gestureState.dx > 120) {
          Animated.spring(position, {
            toValue: { x: SCREEN_WIDTH + 100, y: gestureState.dy },
            useNativedriver: true,
          }).start(() => {
            setIndex(index + 1, () => {
              position.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 })
            })
          })
        } else if (gestureState.dx < -120) {
          Animated.spring(position, {
            toValue: { x: -SCREEN_WIDTH - 100, y: gestureState.dy },
            useNativedriver: true,
          }).start(() => {
            setIndex(index + 1, () => {
              position.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 })
            })
          })
        } else {
          Animated.spring(position, {
            toValue: { x: 0, y: 0 },
            friction: 4,
            useNativedriver: true,
          }).start()
        }
      },
    })
  }, [])

  const Users = () => {
    return imagesData
      .map((item, i) => {
        if (i < index) {
          return null
        } else if (i == index) {
          return (
            <Animated.View
              {...PanResponder.panHandlers}
              key={item.id}
              style={[
                rotateAndTranslate,
                {
                  height: SCREEN_HEIGHT - 120,
                  width: SCREEN_WIDTH,
                  padding: 10,
                  position: 'absolute',
                },
              ]}
            >
              <Animated.View
                style={{
                  opacity: likeOpacity,
                  transform: [{ rotate: '-30deg' }],
                  position: 'absolute',
                  top: 50,
                  left: 40,
                  zIndex: 1000,
                }}
              >
                <Text
                  style={{
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: 'green',
                    color: 'green',
                    fontSize: 32,
                    fontWeight: '800',
                    padding: 10,
                  }}
                >
                  LIKE
                </Text>
              </Animated.View>

              <Animated.View
                style={{
                  opacity: dislikeOpacity,
                  transform: [{ rotate: '30deg' }],
                  position: 'absolute',
                  top: 50,
                  right: 40,
                  zIndex: 1000,
                }}
              >
                <Text
                  style={{
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: 'red',
                    color: 'red',
                    fontSize: 32,
                    fontWeight: '800',
                    padding: 10,
                  }}
                >
                  NOPE
                </Text>
              </Animated.View>

              <Image
                style={{ height: '86%', width: null, borderRadius: 10 }}
                source={{ uri: `${item.url}` }}
              />
              <View
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: '',
                  color: 'black',
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: '800',
                  position: 'absolute',
                  bottom: 95,
                  right: 40,
                  zIndex: 1000,
                  width: '85%',
                  height: '20%',
                  borderRadiusTop: 20,
                }}
              >
                <Text
                  style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 32, fontWeight: '800' }}
                >
                  Black cat
                </Text>
                <Text
                  style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 18, fontWeight: '600' }}
                >
                  Black cat family
                </Text>
                <View style={styles.iconen}>
                  <Ionicons style={styles.icon} name="timer" />
                  <Text style={styles.subtitle}>12 -14</Text>
                  <Ionicons style={styles.icon} name="barbell-outline" />
                  <Text style={styles.subtitle}>12 - 14</Text>
                  <Ionicons style={styles.icon} name="earth" />
                  <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Belgium</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            </Animated.View>
          )
        } else {
          return (
            <Animated.View
              key={item.id}
              style={[
                {
                  opacity: nextCardOpacity,
                  transform: [{ scale: nextCardScale }],
                  height: SCREEN_HEIGHT - 120,
                  width: SCREEN_WIDTH,
                  padding: 10,
                  position: 'absolute',
                },
              ]}
            >
              <Animated.View
                style={{
                  opacity: 0,
                  transform: [{ rotate: '-30deg' }],
                  position: 'absolute',
                  top: 50,
                  left: 40,
                  zIndex: 1000,
                }}
              >
                <Text
                  style={{
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: 'green',
                    color: 'green',
                    fontSize: 32,
                    fontWeight: '800',
                    padding: 10,
                  }}
                >
                  LIKE
                </Text>
              </Animated.View>

              <Animated.View
                style={{
                  opacity: 0,
                  transform: [{ rotate: '30deg' }],
                  position: 'absolute',
                  top: 50,
                  right: 40,
                  zIndex: 1000,
                }}
              >
                <Text
                  style={{
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: 'red',
                    color: 'red',
                    fontSize: 32,
                    fontWeight: '800',
                    padding: 10,
                  }}
                >
                  NOPE
                </Text>
              </Animated.View>

              <Image
                style={{ height: '86%', width: null, borderRadius: 10 }}
                source={{ uri: `${item.url}` }}
              />
            </Animated.View>
          )
        }
      })
      .reverse()
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <View>{Users}</View>
      <View style={{ height: SCREEN_HEIGHT - 80 }}>
        <ButtonVote />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/328193)  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem, such as a specific operation producing an error or an unexpected result, we can help with that.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: You can start by removing everything related to classes like the constructor, the super, this, etc. and rearranging it as a function. Also, everything related to UNSAFE_componentWillMount and such will now be a useEffect. Try that and get back with specific doubts and errors.

Answer (score 1):

**Users** is a component, you should call it like

```
<Users />
```

instead of

```
{Users}
```

Comment: My apologies forgot to change the tags to tsx instead of jsx. Your answer works for jsx, thanks for that but sadly enough not in tsx, I tried to work in jsx but my api request with axios only works with typescrpt

Comment: did you still get the same error?

Comment: No that error is gone, now it gives this error: 'Users' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element. I understand that ImageData is an void but don't know how to give my function the imageData without the void. In jsx it's not a problem but in tsx it sadly is. I could change my axios to something else so I can still use JSX but in all my other projectfiles I'm using tsx.

Comment: I think you just need to add return type for the Users component so that it will not default to void. Best approach would be to make it its own component file

Comment: It works now thanks alot!

Comment: awesome. great work!